# Spring boot Aerospike and Mongo Beans are Conflicting

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, autowired, aerospike

In my application I am using both Mongo and Aerospike.
While creating AerospikeConfig I have to autowire MappingAerospikeConverter and while creating this bean i am getting internal conflicts with bean name.

**ERROR**

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in org.springframework.data.aerospike.convert.MappingAerospikeConverter required a single bean, but 3 were found:
- org.springframework.data.aerospike.convert.CustomConversions: defined in null
- customConversions: defined by method 'customConversions' in class path resource [com/spring/rule/engine/config/RuleEngineConfig.class]
- mongoCustomConversions: defined by method 'mongoCustomConversions' in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDataConfiguration.class]

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.aerospike.cache.AerospikeCacheManager;
import org.springframework.data.aerospike.convert.AerospikeTypeAliasAccessor;
import org.springframework.data.aerospike.convert.MappingAerospikeConverter;
import org.springframework.data.aerospike.mapping.AerospikeMappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.mapping.model.SimpleTypeHolder;

import com.aerospike.client.AerospikeClient;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@Import(value = {MappingAerospikeConverter.class, AerospikeMappingContext.class, AerospikeTypeAliasAccessor.class,
         SimpleTypeHolder.class})
public class AerospikeConfig {

    @Value("${fs.aerospike.hostName}")
    private String hostName;

    @Value("${fs.aerospike.portNumber}")
    private int port;
    
    @Autowired
    private MappingAerospikeConverter mappingAerospikeConverter;
    
    @Bean
    public AerospikeClient aerospike() {
        return new AerospikeClient(hostName, port);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public AerospikeCacheManager cacheManager(AerospikeClient aerospikeClient) {
        return new AerospikeCacheManager(aerospikeClient, mappingAerospikeConverter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to define `mappingAerospikeConverter`, `aerospikeClient` and `aerospikeCacheManager` beans just extend `AbstractAerospikeDataConfiguration` as described below (you can do the same thing in Mongo's configuration class).

I did manage to use both Aerospike and Mongo in the same project.

Versions I used:

Aerospike:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aerospike</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-aerospike</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Mongo (latest):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Configuration classes:

Aerospike:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AerospikeConfigurationProperties.class)
@EnableAerospikeRepositories(basePackageClasses = AerospikeUserRepository.class)
public class AerospikeConfiguration extends AbstractAerospikeDataConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private AerospikeConfigurationProperties aerospikeConfigurationProperties;

    @Override
    protected Collection<Host> getHosts() {
        return Collections.singleton(new Host(aerospikeConfigurationProperties.getHost(), aerospikeConfigurationProperties.getPort()));
    }

    @Override
    protected String nameSpace() {
        return aerospikeConfigurationProperties.getNamespace();
    }
}
```

I used an additional configuration properties class for configuration params and then I passed the values in the application.properties file but its not mandatory:

```
@Data
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "aerospike")
public class AerospikeConfigurationProperties {
    private String host;
    private int port;
    private String namespace;
}
```

Mongo:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = MongoUserRepository.class)
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
# aerospike
aerospike.host=localhost
aerospike.port=3000
aerospike.namespace=test

# mongo
spring.data.mongodb.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.password=example
spring.data.mongodb.database=test
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```